# how to position/resize image after rotation using css/js so that the image is not positioned outside the div holding it or cropped out

Tags: html, css, angularjs, rotation

Here's a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1akhx4yu/)** i'm working on.

The jsfiddle rotates an image upon button click by 90 degrees in clockwise or anti-clockwise direction. The rotated image is displayed outside the parent div when rotated.
The image may be of any height and width.

How can the rotation be modified to display the image within its parent div maintaining its aspect ratio?

```js
var app = angular.module('rotationApp', []);

app.controller('rotationCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.angle = 0;
    $scope.rotate = function(angle) {
      $scope.angle += angle;
      if (($scope.angle === 360)) {
        $scope.angle = 0;
      }
      if ($scope.angle < 0) {
        $scope.angle += 360;
      }
    }
  }
]);

app.directive('rotate', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.degrees, function(rotateDegrees) {
        var r = 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)';
        element.css({
          '-moz-transform': r,
          '-webkit-transform': r,
          '-o-transform': r,
          '-ms-transform': r,
          transform: r
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  border: green solid 1px;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.img-holder {
  border: red solid 1px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='rotationApp' ng-controller="rotationCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 img-holder">
        <img rotate degrees='angle' class="img-responsive" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/3/3a/Pac_man_pie_chart.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100508212204">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="rotate(-90)">
          rotate left
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="rotate(90)">
          rotate right
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS `margin-top` property to do this like this :

```
        var r = 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)';
        element.css({
            '-moz-transform': r,
            '-webkit-transform': r,
            '-o-transform': r,
            '-ms-transform': r,
            transform: r,
            'margin-top' : '100px'
        });
```

And if you want to keep the image stick to the top when it is not rotate, you can add this condition :

```
        if(r == "rotate(0deg)" || r == "rotate(180deg)"){
            element.css('margin-top',0);
        }
```

[See the result here](https://jsfiddle.net/1akhx4yu/4/)

**Note** : If you remove that last condition, it is perfectly centered to the border.